# Create an Excel file using xlsxwriter issue

Tags: python, xlsxwriter

I'm new to Python and I'm having issues with the following script:

```
#modules

import time
import os
import xlsxwriter

#the path for where all the things the progrem these should happen
PATH = r"C:\status\status"
#gives you the date and time used for the name of the mother file
DATE = time.strftime('%d,%m')

#creatss a file for xls
def xl():
    xl =  cyberboad = os.makedirs(r"C:\status\status" + '\\' + DATE + '\\' + "XL")

#creatss the file tree for cyberboard with one file for ech opration and xl workbooks in ech file with oprations file
def cyberboad():
    cyberboad = os.makedirs(r"C:\status\status" + '\\' + DATE + '\\' + "CYBERBOARD")
    #operations
    operation1010 = os.makedirs(r"C:\status\status" + '\\' + DATE + '\\' + "CYBERBOARD" + '\\' + "1010")
    os.chdir(r"C:\status\status" + '\\' + DATE + '\\' + "CYBERBOARD" + '\\' + "1010")
    workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('mazehim.xlsx')
    worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
    bold = workbook.add_format({'bold': True})
    worksheet.write('A1', 'getfile', bold)
    worksheet.write('C1', 'dir', bold)
    operation90247 = os.makedirs(r"C:\status\status" + '\\' + DATE + '\\' + "CYBERBOARD" + '\\' + "90247")
    #creates the xl workbook for ech file and writes in it get file,dir at the top of  colum A,C
    os.chdir(r"C:\status\status" + '\\' + DATE + '\\' + "CYBERBOARD" + '\\' + "90247")
    workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('mazehim.xlsx')
    worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
    bold = workbook.add_format({'bold': True})
    worksheet.write('A1', 'getfile', bold)
    worksheet.write('C1', 'dir', bold)
    operation9969 = os.makedirs(r"C:\status\status" + '\\' + DATE + '\\' + "CYBERBOARD" + '\\' + "9969")
    os.chdir(r"C:\status\status" + '\\' + DATE + '\\' + "CYBERBOARD" + '\\' + "9969")
    workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('mazehim.xlsx')
    worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
    bold = workbook.add_format({'bold': True})
    worksheet.write('A1', 'getfile', bold)
    worksheet.write('C1', 'dir', bold)
    operation90665 = os.makedirs(r"C:\status\status" + '\\' + DATE + '\\' + "CYBERBOARD" + '\\' + "90665")
    os.chdir(r"C:\status\status" + '\\' + DATE + '\\' + "CYBERBOARD" + '\\' + "90665")
    workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('mazehim.xlsx')
    worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
    bold = workbook.add_format({'bold': True})
    worksheet.write('A1', 'getfile', bold)
    worksheet.write('C1', 'dir', bold)
    operationmatchupzone = os.makedirs(r"C:\status\status" + '\\' + DATE + '\\' + "CYBERBOARD" + '\\' + "matchupzone")
    os.chdir(r"C:\status\status" + '\\' + DATE + '\\' + "CYBERBOARD" + '\\' + "matchupzone")
    workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('mazehim.xlsx')
    worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
    bold = workbook.add_format({'bold': True})
    worksheet.write('A1', 'getfile', bold)
    worksheet.write('C1', 'dir', bold)

#creatss the file tree for allrivers with one file for ech opration and xl workbooks in ech file with oprations file
def allrivers():
    allrivers = os.makedirs(r"C:\status\status" + '\\' + DATE + '\\' + "ALLRIVERS")
    #operations
    operation5553 = os.makedirs(r"C:\status\status" + '\\' + DATE + '\\' + "ALLRIVERS" + '\\' + "5553")
    os.chdir(r"C:\status\status" + '\\' + DATE + '\\' + "ALLRIVERS" + '\\' + "5553")
    workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('mazehim.xlsx')
    worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
    bold = workbook.add_format({'bold': True})
    worksheet.write('A1', 'getfile', bold)
    worksheet.write('C1', 'dir', bold)
    operation8256 = os.makedirs(r"C:\status\status" + '\\' + DATE + '\\' + "ALLRIVERS" + '\\' + "8256")
    os.chdir(r"C:\status\status" + '\\' + DATE + '\\' + "ALLRIVERS" + '\\' + "8256")
    workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(' mazehim.xlsx')
    worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
    bold = workbook.add_format({'bold': True})
    worksheet.write('A1', 'getfile', bold)
    worksheet.write('C1', 'dir', bold)
    operationeberkiss = os.makedirs(r"C:\status\status" + '\\' + DATE + '\\' + "ALLRIVERS" + '\\' + "emberkiss")
    os.chdir(r"C:\status\status" + '\\' + DATE + '\\' + "ALLRIVERS" + '\\' + "emberkiss")
    workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('mazehim.xlsx')
    worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
    bold = workbook.add_format({'bold': True})
    worksheet.write('A1', 'getfile', bold)
    worksheet.write('C1', 'dir', bold)
    operationlaguardia = os.makedirs(r"C:\status\status" + '\\' + DATE + '\\' + "ALLRIVERS" + '\\' + "laguardia")
    os.chdir(r"C:\status\status" + '\\' + DATE + '\\' + "ALLRIVERS" + '\\' + "laguardia")
    workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('mazehim.xlsx')
    worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
    bold = workbook.add_format({'bold': True})
    worksheet.write('A1', 'getfile', bold)
    worksheet.write('C1', 'dir', bold)
    operation1024 = os.makedirs(r"C:\status\status" + '\\' + DATE + '\\' + "ALLRIVERS" + '\\' + "1024")
    os.chdir(r"C:\status\status" + '\\' + DATE + '\\' + "ALLRIVERS" + '\\' + "1024")
    workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('mazehim.xlsx')
    worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
    bold = workbook.add_format({'bold': True})
    worksheet.write('A1', 'getfile', bold)
    worksheet.write('C1', 'dir', bold)

#calling the fenctions set above
cyberboad()
allrivers()
xl()
```

I know it is not a very clean script, what it does is it creates a folder and then inside that folder it creates an Excel file using the module `xlsxwriter`.

It works fine but sometimes it doesn't. What am I doing wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: what do you mean by "4 out of 5"? it succeed in probability of 80% or it always succeed the first 4 and then, the next one fail?
dows it always the same folders which it fail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it can be many things and its is hard to tell when the code is wrote in such way. but here couple of problems I noticed:

1. **you override your `workbook` again and again.** you should create it once. and use the same workbook object
2. you forgot to close the workbook (just add `workbook.close()` in the end)
3. im not sure your `xl` does what you meant. it only create a "XL" folder

please try to simplify the code and explain better what is going wrong.
you can try this simplified code:

```
import time
import os
import xlsxwriter

#the path for where all the things the progrem these should happen
PATH = r"C:\status\status"
#gives you the date and time used for the name of the mother file
DATE = time.strftime('%d,%m')
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('mazehim.xlsx')
bold = workbook.add_format({'bold': True})

#creatss a file for xls
def xl():
    os.makedirs(PATH + '\\' + DATE + '\\' + "XL")

#creatss the file tree for cyberboard with one file for ech opration and xl workbooks in ech file with oprations file
def cyberboad():
    cyberboad = os.makedirs(r"C:\status\status" + '\\' + DATE + '\\' + "CYBERBOARD")    

    #operations
    for f in ["1010","90247","9969","90665","matchupzone"]:
        os.makedirs(PATH + '\\' + DATE + '\\' + "CYBERBOARD" + '\\' + f)
        os.chdir(PATH + '\\' + DATE + '\\' + "CYBERBOARD" + '\\' + f)
        worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
        worksheet.write('A1', 'getfile', bold)
        worksheet.write('C1', 'dir', bold)

#creatss the file tree for allrivers with one file for ech opration and xl workbooks in ech file with oprations file
def allrivers():
    allrivers = os.makedirs(r"C:\status\status" + '\\' + DATE + '\\' + "ALLRIVERS")
    #operations
    for f in ["5553","8256","emberkiss","laguardia","1024"]:
        os.makedirs(PATH + '\\' + DATE + '\\' + "ALLRIVERS" + '\\' + f)
        os.chdir(PATH + '\\' + DATE + '\\' + "ALLRIVERS" + '\\' + f)    
        worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()    
        worksheet.write('A1', 'getfile', bold)
        worksheet.write('C1', 'dir', bold)

#calling the fenctions set above
cyberboad()
allrivers()
xl()

workbook.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import time
import os
import xlsxwriter

#the path for where all the things the progrem these should happen
PATH = r"C:\status\status"
#gives you the date and time used for the name of the mother file
DATE = time.strftime('%d,%m')


#creatss a file for xls
def xl():
    os.makedirs(PATH + '\\' + DATE + '\\' + "XL")

#creatss the file tree for cyberboard with one file for ech opration and xl workbooks in ech file with oprations file
def cyberboad():
    cyberboad = os.makedirs(r"C:\status\status" + '\\' + DATE + '\\' + "CYBERBOARD")

    #operations
    for f in ["1010","90247","9969","90665","matchupzone"]:
        os.makedirs(PATH + '\\' + DATE + '\\' + "CYBERBOARD" + '\\' + f)
        os.chdir(PATH + '\\' + DATE + '\\' + "CYBERBOARD" + '\\' + f)
        workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('mazehim.xlsx')
        worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
        bold = workbook.add_format({'bold': True})
        worksheet.write('A1', 'getfile', bold)
        worksheet.write('C1', 'dir', bold)
        workbook.close()

#creatss the file tree for allrivers with one file for ech opration and xl workbooks in ech file with oprations file
def allrivers():
    allrivers = os.makedirs(r"C:\status\status" + '\\' + DATE + '\\' + "ALLRIVERS")
    #operations
    for f in ["5553","8256","emberkiss","laguardia","1024"]:
        os.makedirs(PATH + '\\' + DATE + '\\' + "ALLRIVERS" + '\\' + f)
        os.chdir(PATH + '\\' + DATE + '\\' + "ALLRIVERS" + '\\' + f)
        workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('mazehim.xlsx')
        worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
        bold = workbook.add_format({'bold': True})
        worksheet.write('A1', 'getfile', bold)
        worksheet.write('C1', 'dir', bold)
        workbook.close()

#calling the fenctions set above
cyberboad()
allrivers()
xl()
```

hey just want to let you know that the code works as intended now and am happy with it thanks for the help and have a nice day 
and of course the above code is the finished product